# plucking out of an object

Tags: object, underscore.js

I recently was able to chain some underscore to map pull some values out of an array of objects.  However, I have received some context that I cannot pluck out of.  Here is what is in my console from the object I created

```
Object {family: 45, rest: 60, personal: 145, work: 180}
```

When I call

```
_.pluck(Object, "family") I get an empty array.
```

I have also tried to call by the name of the object.

```
_.pluck(groupMinuteTotal, 'family')
```

I keep getting undefined 4 times in an array.

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[_.pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) can either be called against an Array of Objects or an Object where every value is an object itself with the key you are 'plucking'. You could use it like :

```
var group = [{family: 45, rest: 60, personal: 145, work: 180}, {family: 3, rest: 60, personal: 145, work: 180}];
_.pluck(group, 'family'); // [45, 3]
```

You could also use it like this :

```
var group =  { 'john' : {family: 45, rest: 60 }, 'max' : {family: 3, rest: 60} };
_.pluck(group, 'family'); // [45, 3] (order not guaranteed)
```

In your case it is trying to pull the key 'family' off of each value in the object, which returns undefined because the numbers don't have a value for that key.

If you provide some more context about what you are trying to achieve it may be easier to provide a better/alternate solution. If you just have a single object, you should just call `groupMinuteTotal['family']` to get the value. If it's the result of a chained operation, just call value() to retrieve the chained object:

```
_.chain(collection)
...other operations resulting in a single object...
.value()['family'];
```